# Is it possible to iterate through only half of the provided hashmap entries?

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

I have a `Hashmap< String, String> p` and I'm trying to replace half of the values of the keys with '-'
For instance, lets say my current Hashmap has the following values

```
"A", "100"
"B", "400"
"C", "600"
"D", "845"
```

I want to somehow manipulate only half (first two in this case) of the key of the values by changing their values from the provided integer to a '-'.
So it would look like this:

```
    "A", "-"
    "B", "-"
    "C", "600"
    "D", "845"
```

I've attempted this, but to no avail.

```
for (String i : p.keySet()/2) {
  p.replace(i, '-')
}
```

Is there a way to do this? If yes, can you please explain how?

Comment: Of course that is possible, by writing the right code.

Comment: can you please explain how?

Comment: by learning Java

Comment: @jwenting well I am currently learning sir, and I have also attempted to solve it.

Comment: I'm just stuck at this bit, which is why I'm asking

Comment: so what have you done to try to solve it? Personally, I 'm not even sure your solution would compile. check the size of the Map, then only get the items that are max half it's index

Comment: Given that a `HashMap` is unordered you would first need to define "half".  Your sample conveniently lists the map in an apparent order but that is not a result of the map.

Comment: Java doesn't allow you to directly divide a Set by 2. Once you have an ordered list of the map's entries, you'll need to iterate up to the index half-way through the map (.keySet().size()/2) and edit the values at this index

Comment: Your title question is "print half the map".  Therefore, (1) decide the criteria for printing an entry or not, (2) encode that decision in a 'if' statement inside a loop through all map entries.

Comment: But your example code, replacing values by "-", has nothing at all to do with printing anything, so it's not really clear what you want.

Comment: I want to replace half of all the key's values with "-" instead of the values originally present

Comment: For map 'h': `Map<String, String> mNew = h.entrySet().stream().limit(h.entrySet().size()/2).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> "-"));
`

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, but I'm still left wondering what the point is.  Since HashMaps have no predictable iteration order, you're modifying an unpredictable set of entries.

Comment: Quite right. Maybe all will be revealed... ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
int maxiterations = p.keySet().size() / 2;
Iterator<String> iterator = p.keySet().iterator();
for (int i=0; i < maxiterations; i++) {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        p.replace(key, "-");
    }
}
```

Or

```
int iterations = p.keySet().size() / 2;
do {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        p.replace(iterator.next(), "-");
    }
} while (--iterations > 0);
```

Comment: In the first example, why the need for hasNext?  It can only be false if entries are being concurrently removed, but in that case synchronization is needed anyway.

Comment: @accessviolation I don't know what correspondent want to do. It's better to be safe.

Comment: But there is no point in continuing the loop once `hasNext()` returned `false`. So just add it to the loop’s condition, i.e. `for(int i = 0; i < maxiterations && iterator.hasNext(); i++) { String key = iterator.next(); p.replace(key, "-"); }`

Answer (score 6):

Another solution:

```
    p.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .limit(p.size()/2)
        .forEach(e-> e.setValue("-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can learn from this

```
   Map<Integer, Integer> map= new HashMap<>();
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           map.put(i,i);
       }
       int half=map.size()/2;
       int count=0;
       for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> cm: map.entrySet()) {
           if (!((count++) < half))) { // if my count is greater than half
               System.out.println(cm.getKey() + " " + cm.getValue());
           }
       }
```

Now Evaluate and solve

add this else

```
         else{
                System.out.println(cm.getKey() + " _ ");
            }
```

Comment: One ')' expected, and may most clear this: `if (++count < half) ...`, which takes first half of the map. Your code takes second half.

Answer (score 0):

another way to do that

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap< String, String> p = new HashMap<>();
    p.put("A", "100");
    p.put("B", "400");
    p.put("C", "600");
    p.put("D", "845");

    int halfSize = (p.size() / 2)+1;

    for(String key : p.keySet()){
        halfSize =  halfSize-1;
        if (halfSize == 0){
            break;
        }else{
            p.replace(key, "-");
        }
    }

    for (String key : p.keySet()){
        System.out.println(p.get(key));
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may do something similar to:

```
String[] keys = capitalCities.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
for(int i=0 ; i<keys.length/2 ; i++)
        capitalCities.put(keys[i],"-");
```